# How to use foreach variable in some other make variable for every loop run in makefile?

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make

Consider i  have a target consisting of foreach loop in makefile

```
# variables
CONFIG = 1 2 3
LOG_DIR=CONFIG_$(VAR)

# targets

run:
    running application

run_configs:
    $(foreach VAR, $(CONFIG), make run CONFIGRATION=$(VAR) logging ; )

build_dir:
    mkdir $(LOG_DIR)/

logging: build_dir
    cp logdata/* $(LOG_DIR)/.
```

On running the foreach target

```
make run_configs

running application with CONFIG=1
making logdata
cp logdata/* CONFIG_/.
```

The directory expected was CONFIG_1 but built was CONFIG_

I understand the makefile is parsed first so, the variable LOG_DIR is evaluated as CONFIG_
because the foreach variable VAR is null at the time.

I cant find a way to update the LOG_DIR variable every time foreach loop is executed.

Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um...?  When you invoke the recursive make you're setting the variable `CONFIGRATION`:

```
make run CONFIGRATION=$(VAR)
```

but when you construct the variable you're using `$(VAR)`:

```
LOG_DIR=CONFIG_$(VAR)
```

`CONFIGRATION` is not the same as `VAR`.  You need to either pass `VAR` to the submake:

```
make run VAR=$(VAR)
```

or use `CONFIGRATION` when building the variable:

```
LOG_DIR=CONFIG_$(CONFIGRATION)
```

Comment: Passing variable to sub-make worked flawlessly. Is there any way to automatically pass all such variable to sub-make targets ?

Comment: You'll have to define what "such variables" means... all which variables?